# Asymptotically analyzing a sum: is the following sum asymptotically polynomial in n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

For 0<p<1, is the following sum asymptotically polynomial in n as $n\to \infty$:

$$\sum _{k=0}^n \left(2 p^{2^{k-1}}\right)^k \binom{n}{k}$$

If so, what would be the polynomial approxiamation? If not, what would be a meaningful approximation, or other bounds?

As of now I think I could show that it is not exponential...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Q: Find an approximation for,
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (2p^{2^{k-1}})^k {n \choose k}
$$
A: The main idea here is to split the sum into good and bad sections. First, let's rephrase the question a little. Let $r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}} > 1$, then $$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (2r^{-2^k})^k {n \choose k}$$

Now with the weak estimate ${n \choose k} \leq n^k$, we get

$$
S_n \leq \sum_{k=0}^n r^{-k2^k} (2n)^k
$$

If we can find the value $M$ after which the summand becomes less than 1, we'll be able to turn all the terms after that into a linear term.

So we want to find $M$ such that for all $k>M$,
$$
r^{k2^k} \geq (2n)^k
$$

Putting both sides to the power $1/k$, we only require
$$
r^{2^k} \geq 2n \iff 2^k \geq \frac{\log(2n)}{\log (r)}
$$

So $M = \log\left(\frac{\log(2n)}{\log (r)}\right)$ and we get

$$
\sum_{k \geq M}^n r^{-k2^k} (2n)^k \leq \sum_{k \geq M}^n 1 \leq n
$$

Now let's look at the beginning part of the sum. Note that $M \leq \log\log(2n)$. For all $k<M$, we have that
$$
(2n)^k \leq 2^{\log (2n) \left[\log\log(2n)-\log\log(r)\right]} \leq 2^{\log (2n) \log\log(2n)} = (2n)^{\log\log 2n} = n^{\log\log (2n)} \log(n)
$$

We know that $r^{-k 2^k} < 1$ so we can ignore this term. So for the first sum we have
$$
\sum_{k \leq M} r^{-k2^k} (2n)^k \leq M (2n)^M \leq \log(n)\log\log(2n)n^{\log\log(n)}
$$

Combining both parts of the sum we have
$$
S_n = O(\log(n)\log\log(n)n^{\log\log(n)}) = O(\log(n^{\log\log(n)})n^{\log\log(n)})
$$

Not quite a polynomial estimate but pretty close (if $n$ is the number of atoms in the universe, $\log\log (n)$ is about 8).

Edit: $${n \choose k} = \frac{n(n-1)\ldots (n-k-1)}{k(k-1)\ldots(2)(1)} \geq \frac{(n-k-1)^k}{k^k}$$ so substituting k = 1, 2, 3, ... we actually show that we can't get a polynomial bound unfortunately, as $(2r^{-2^k})^k$ is independent of $n$. Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Just edited my answer to show that we cannot get a polynomial bound.

Comment: Yes, that's really neat, and with (n k) >= (n-k+1)^k /k^k too. Both estimates are very useful: It is not a polynomial in theory, but is one for virtually all practical uses.